# Jquery/Javascript : Negative of a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to check for the negative of a variable?

Here are my variables:

```
var frameWidth = 400;
var imageWidth = parseInt($('#' + divId).find('#inner-image').css('width'), 10);
var imageMargin = parseInt($('#' + divId).find('#inner-image').css('margin-left'), 10);
var numberOfFrames = imageWidth/frameWidth;
```

I want to perform a check kind of like this:

```
if (imageMargin == -numberOfFrames*frameWidth-400 )
```

But I don't know how.

In other words, if numberOfFrames*frameWidth-400 equals 800, I need it to return -800.

Thanks again for any direction you can provide.

Answer (score 9):

There should be no problems if you put parenthesis around the value you want to negate:

```
if (imageMargin == -(numberOfFrames*frameWidth-400) )
   ...
```

Comment: @Rrryyyaaannn If the result of `(numberOfFrames*frameWidth-400)` is itself negative then the expression above will check for the positive... is that OK? @Matt's function getNegativeOf() will always return the negative.

Answer (score 4):

If you always want a negative value, and you don't know if it'll be positive or negative:

```
function getNegativeOf(val) {
    return Math.abs(val) * -1;
};
```

Then use as:

```
var guaranteedNegativeImageWidth = getNegativeOf(parseInt($('#' + divId).find('#inner-image').css('width'), 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about subtracting it from zero?

```
if (imageMargin == (0-(numberOfFrames*frameWidth-400)) )
```